# Assistance with Compiling Synergy KVM Software

Tags: xcode, qt, compilation

I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Compiling for compiling on OSX. I've "finished" everything. But I don't understand what to do to install synergy once the compiler has completed? I was expecting a nice output directory somewhere with a synergy.app or something in it. Am I missing something? I've used the GUI method using QT to compile the code as I didnt scroll down far enough initially to realise you can do it on the command line. But either way I've managed to get to the end of the instructions for compiling and I'm a little lost now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once it's compiled, Synergy binaries are outputted to the `build/bin` directory inside whatever directory you cloned the Synergy source to (it was `~/git/synergy-core` in my case).

You can run `~/git/synergy-core/build/bin/synergy` (replacing with whatever your path is) to start the Synergy configuration UI which lets you configure your server or client as desired.